How to use NewExpandableDocumentCommand with a foreach inside a TikZ-matrix
Follow-up question to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714853/46023

I have the command
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\test}{O{} m}{%
\foreach[count=\no from 0] \No in {1,...,#2}{%%
\node[draw, yshift=-5.5mm*\no, #1]{\No};
}%%
}

and it works inside a {tikzpicture}.
But if I put it into a TikZ-matrix it does not work. 
What do I have to do?

\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\test}{O{} m}{%
\foreach[count=\no from 0] \No in {1,...,#2}{%%
\node[draw, yshift=-5.5mm*\no, #1]{\No};
}%%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\test{3} 
\test[red, xshift=1cm]{5} 
\node[yshift=6mm, xshift=5mm] {works here};

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, draw, 
xshift=3cm, label={[align=left, font=\slshape]but not here \\ in the matrix},
]{
a & b \\
%\test{3}   &  \test[red, xshift=1cm]{5} \\ % Does not work
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\NewExpandableDocumentCommand is not a magic wand that makes expandable what isn't such. But did you try with the \foreach directly in the matrix? Well, it doesn't work.

This is unrelated to xparse and \NewDocumentCommand, you would  get the same error just using \pgfor... inline in the matrix.

a matrix of nodes means every cell is like the content of a \node and  so your "works here" comparision should be \node {\test{e}} (which fails as well)
Unrelated but you should use \NewDocumentCommand not \NewExpandableDocumentCommand as pgf \foreach isn't expandable anyway so there is no advantage (and some disadvantages) to declaring an expandable argument processor for it.
